# Where is a two-handed gun outside of Megaton?

Tags: fallout-3

Is there a two-handed gun outside of Megaton in *Fallout 3*? Where can I find one?

Comment: I think you'd get more answers if you removed all but one of those 'p's at the end of your question title (with the 'edit' link). :)

Comment: Try changing the title of your question to "Where is a two handed gun outside of Megaton in Fallout 3?"

Comment: I voted to close, but then I thought better and edited it. I'll vote to re-open if it gets closed. Feel free to improve it further.

Comment: You're going to have to define "outside of Megaton"; almost every gun in the game is outside of Megaton. I assume you mean the best close one to Megaton, but then you have to weigh weapon quality against distance, which is subjective.

Comment: I would like to see the xbox-360 tag removed as this question is platform-agnostic. I won't remove it just yet as 2 mods have edited the tags on the wuestion and both of them chose ot leave it in...

Answer (score 10):

Outside of Megaton, to the left behind where the saloon would be (facing in towards megaton) there is a 'hollowed out rock'.  I don't think it shows on the pip boy, but if you move your cross hairs over it, it will say something like 'Open hollowed out rock'.

There are 2 or three molerats around, at least at lower levels.

Inside is some food, a note and a sniper rifle with some ammo. Can't remember if there was anything else there.

edit: removed ascii map because I can't make it work :P

check the fallout wiki here: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hollowed-out_rock_(Fallout_3)

Comment: The hollow rock is one of the few reliable places to get a sniper rifle.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you can find some decent weapons in Springvale school just northwest of Megaton. There's probably a hunting rifle or two, possibly even an assault rifle. It's chock full of raiders, but that's usually my first stop to pick up weapons, ammo, and a bit of loot. If you're careful you shouldn't have to take on more than one or two raiders at a time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you really mean "where are the closest two-handed guns to Megaton"; see my comment to the question. If so, you don't even have to leave town. Accept Mr. Burke's offer to detonate the bomb, turn him in to Lucas Simms — don't say you're kidding, you'll lose the option of telling him later — and you'll be able to take the sheriff's Chinese Assault Rifle after the scripted sequence.

If you don't care about negative karma, you could also just kill Lucas Simms or Jericho right off the bat; each of them carries a Chinese Assault Rifle. If you do get to loot Lucas Simms's corpse for whatever reason, you'll get his house key; the game doesn't make it clear, but the same key opens the Megaton armory, which contains lots of weapons including some more two-handed guns. Beware, there's also a Mister Gutsy guard inside, and he'll take low-level characters apart pretty easily.

Comment: +1 Min effort max reward on the Burke/Simms quest. That's how I got my ever reliable Chinese Assault Rifle first time through. The Sheriff's outfit's personality bonuses make it a good in-town outfit for haggling and chatting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Like everywhere. Hunting rifles and assault rifles are very commonplace everywhere, not just Megaton.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [Wasteland Survival Guide](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wasteland_Survival_Guide_(quest)) quest line, you will find the quest called `Traversing a mine field` that will lead you to a [minefield](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Minefield) where you will encounter an NPC named [Arkansas](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arkansas) who wields a sniper rifle.

This area is fairly dangerous, so tread carefully. You may find some bugs or molerats to kill but will most definitely encounter [frag mines](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Frag_mine_(Fallout_3)) that can be somewhat difficult to disarm in certain spots.

In any case, find and kill Arkansas to acquire his sniper rifle.